# Swift: Terminating app with uncaught exception type NSException

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, alamofire

I'm using an open source app example in my project.

When I change the Facebook credentials in info.plist, I get this "**terminating with uncaught exception error**".

But when I revert to the default(as used in initial open source application), I don't get any crash/error and app works smoothly.

I can't figure out the exception from this code, can anyone help ?

```
@IBAction func facebookLogin(sender: UIButton) {

        PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], block: { (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if user != nil {
                if user[PF_USER_FACEBOOKID] == nil {
                    self.requestFacebook(user)
                } else {
                    self.userLoggedIn(user)
                }
            } else {
                if error != nil {
                    println(error)
                    if let info = error.userInfo {
                        println(info)
                    }
                }
                MBProgressHUD.showError("Facebook sign in error")
            }
        })
    }

    func requestFacebook(user: PFUser) {
        var request = FBRequest.requestForMe()
        request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection: FBRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                var userData = result as! [String: AnyObject]!
                self.processFacebook(user, userData: userData)
            } else {
                PFUser.logOut()

            }
        }
    }

    func processFacebook(user: PFUser, userData: [String: AnyObject]) {
        let facebookUserId = userData["id"] as! String
        var link = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(facebookUserId)/picture"
        let url = NSURL(string: link)
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let params = ["height": "150", "width": "150", "type": "square"]
        Alamofire.request(.GET, link, parameters: params).response() {
            (request, response, data, error) in

            if error == nil {
                var image = UIImage(data: data! as! NSData)!

                if image.size.width > 280 {
                    image = Images.resizeImage(image, width: 280, height: 280)!
                }
                var filePicture = PFFile(name: "picture.jpg", data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6))
                filePicture.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {
                        println("Error saving photo")
                    }
                })

                if image.size.width > 60 {
                    image = Images.resizeImage(image, width: 60, height: 60)!
                }
                var fileThumbnail = PFFile(name: "thumbnail.jpg", data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6))
                fileThumbnail.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {
                        prinln("Error saving thumbnail")
                    }
                })

                user[PF_USER_EMAILCOPY] = userData["email"]
                user[PF_USER_FULLNAME] = userData["name"]
                user[PF_USER_FULLNAME_LOWER] = (userData["name"] as! String).lowercaseString
                user[PF_USER_FACEBOOKID] = userData["id"]
                user[PF_USER_PICTURE] = filePicture
                user[PF_USER_THUMBNAIL] = fileThumbnail
                user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.userLoggedIn(user)
                    } else {
                        PFUser.logOut()
                        if let info = error!.userInfo {
                            ProgressHUD.showError("Login error")
                            println(info["error"] as! String)
                        }
                    }
                })
            } else {
                PFUser.logOut()
                if let info = error!.userInfo {
                    prinln("Failed to fetch Facebook photo")
                    println(info["error"] as! String)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what I get when the app crashes: "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull

....
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: What error do you get? And show us what you've changed in your plist.

Comment: Enable break on exceptions in xcode and tell us what and where do you get.

Comment: Hey @Christian: This is the error in console. "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'" I've just changed the FacebookAppId and URL Types fd"id" ..

Comment: Please add this information to your question.(Also the error you've shown in the comments)

Comment: The only values I've changed in the previously working application are the URL Types -> URL schemes -> fb"id" and FacebookAppId as I've informed and nothing else. when I check my Parse backend, I don't get email, fullname fetched .

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark:
Has it something to do with the escape sequence in your link:

**\**(facebookUserId)
?

Comment: But, that didn't occur when I've run the example code as it is. This crash only occurred when (as mentioned) I've replaced the info.plist keys of URL Typed (fb"id") and FacebookAppID. If, after this crash, I reuse the same old fb keys, the app runs perfectly alright without any crash. Something I'm unable to get grips with.

Comment: ah you changed only two values in info.plist, 'fb"id"' and 'FacebookAppID', wow thats interesting, maybe you copied some not unicode character in the values, or renamed the attribute name on the left side of the table ? Just guessing, but you must be close :)

Comment: This problem is occurring only when the fb login button is pressed. The other (email) login and register options are working fine. I haven't copied any non-unicode values.